# Preconditions in Swift and Testing Them

Tags: swift, testing, assertions

In Java I can use frameworks like Guava to check method preconditions, for example like this:

```
public void doSomething(int index) {
  Preconditions.checkArgument(index >= 3);
  // do something
}
```

And I can then test them like this:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testDoSomething() {
  sut.doSomething(2);
}
```

**How can I do the same thing in Swift?**

I know about Swift's assertions, but I don't know how you would test for them.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use preconditions in Swift by using `precondition`. Like that:

```
func test(hello:String){
    precondition(hello == "Hello", "String is Hello")

}
```

For example, in the Swift REPL:

```
> test("Hello")
> test("Hellox")
precondition failed: String is Hello: file /var/folders/z3/kd0nj4ln1rgcpm8bdz7067wh0000gs/T/./lldb/566/repl1.swift, line 2
Execution interrupted. Enter Swift code to recover and continue.
```

Comment: @GoZoner Thanks for your edit. Didn't know about Swift REPL yet.

Comment: And … how do I write the corresponding test for it?